# Change modal content dynamically in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

> 1. I have a GSP page which contents modal.
> 2. I made the modal div into a
>      separate GSP layout, which is to be dynamic with the different values.
> 3. More than one div OnClick method pointing same data-target, but
>      those div have different parameters to get dynamic output from point 2.

Now my requirement is changing the data-target div (point 2) contains dynamically as the different div is clicked (point 3).

**Different div pointing same data:**

```
<input type="text" hidden name="latitude" id="projectName1" value= ${property?.propertyAddress?.buildingName}>
<input type="text" hidden name="longitude" id="property1" value= ${property?.id}>
<input type="text" hidden name="latitude" id="projectName2" value= ${property2?.propertyAddress?.buildingName}>
<input type="text" hidden name="longitude" id="property2" value= ${property2?.id}>
<div class="system-link" id="project1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-blog-post">View Project Information</div>
<div class="system-link" id="project2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-blog-post">View Project Information2</div>
```

**And Dynamic page to be refreshed as per click is (here is above two different div OnClick):**

```
<div id="add-blog-post" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 95%;">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 10px;">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <h3>Project Information</h3>
        <input type="text" hidden name="latitude" id="latitude" value= ${property.propertyAddress.latitude}>
        <input type="text" hidden name="longitude" id="longitude" value= ${property.propertyAddress.longitude}>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Property Type</td>
                <td>${project?.propertyType}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>District</td>
                <td>District ${project?.district}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Yes i am using twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First maybe you should lose the data-toggle and data-target because they will not be neccesary and you need to control when the modal is shown.

Then it might be easier to either put an `<a>` inside your `<div>` or create an `<a>` instead of your `<div>`. There is also de possibility of adding a data- attribute to your div. I´ll take the link route.

```
...    
<a class="system-link" id="project1" 
       href="${createlink(controller: 'yourController', action: 'getData', id: project1ID)}">
  View Project Information
</a>
<a class="system-link" id="project2"        
         href="${createlink(controller: 'yourController', action: 'getData', id: project2ID)}">
  View Project Information2
 </a>
```

For your modal you would need to add a div#project-info that will act as your ajax target. Also, keep your modal in the same gsp as your links.

```
<div id="add-blog-post" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 95%;">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 10px;">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" id="project-info">
        </div> <!--Project info DIV-->
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You will also need to create a template (ex:_projectData.gsp), that will contain only the data of the desired project.

```
  <h3>Project Information</h3>
  <input type="text" hidden name="latitude" id="latitude" value= ${property.propertyAddress.latitude}>
  <input type="text" hidden name="longitude" id="longitude" value= ${property.propertyAddress.longitude}>

  <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Property Type</td>
         <td>${project?.propertyType}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>District</td>
          <td>District ${project?.district}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

The controller action that retrieves the data from the server will have something along the lines of

```
def getData(long id){
    def projectInstance = Project.read(id)  
    ... 
    render template: 'projectData', model: [projectInstance: projectInstance]
}
```

Finally you will need a script that will controll the retrieval of the ajax data.

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".system-link").on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var activeLink = $(this); //get the active link
                var modal = $("#add-blog-post"); //get your modal
                var target = $("#project-info"); //get your ajax target
                var ajarUrl = activeLink.prop('href');  //This is the url to call


                $.get(ajarUrl)
                .done(function(ajaxData){
                        target.html(data);      
                        modal.modal('show'); //Show the modal after the content of the div is populated     
                })
                .fail(function(){
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                });             

            }); // Click event handler
        });  //Document ready
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```